# How to get the variables out of a new thread?

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading

How can i get the variables out of a new thread created with:

```
public class ParseJson 
{
    public static String parsejson(String strHttpGet)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public String run(String strHttpGet)
            {
                String decodeJson = "someJson";
                return decodeJson;
            }
        });
            thread.start();
    }
}
```

I mean how can i get back the decoded json to my function parseJson and give it back to my function call `String decodedJson = ParseJson.parseJson(strHttpGet);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android, which you have tagged this question as, it would be simpler to use AsyncTask for this situation, because when you override the `onPostEXecute` method you can put in all sorts of things:

- update the UI
- send intents and messages
- access variables of the parent class if the AsyncTask class is defined inside it.

  ```
  class MyClass {
      Button b;
      boolean flag = false;
      // Stuff

      class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask {
          // All the stuff, core work in doInBackground

          @Override
          void onPostExecute(/*vars*/) {
              b.setText("Done");
              flag = true;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- General principles for using AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
- tutorial: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.co.uk/p/android-asynctask-example.html
- tutorial: http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Answer (score 1):

You can't *return a value* from a `Thread` in Java. Actually, [`run()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()) doesn't have a return type.

You could use a shared custom `Object` that will hold the result. Declare it as `final`, so you can access it in the anonymous subclass (that would be equivalent to passing a reference to the subclass), and just call a setter on it when the work is done.

```
public class ParseJson {
    public static String parsejson(final String strHttpGet) {
        final StringHolder ob = new MyObject();
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public String run() {
                String decodeJson = "someJson";
                ob.setResult(decodeJson);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    private static class StringHolder (){
        private String result;
        public String getResult() { return result; }
        public void setResult(String r) { result = r; }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I understood why you said *get back the decoded json to my function parseJson and give it back to my function call*. Do you mean you'll just wait in that function until  the `Thread` is finished? If that's what you want (again, why start a `Thread`?), you could use [`Thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()).

Although if you want to get notified when the `Thread` finishes, you should indeed look into another option. Neil and Waqas have given [good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970652/851811) [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970858/851811).

Answer (score 0):

You may even use an [**`Observer/Observable`**](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-howto.html) pattern for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

```
public class Json {
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public static String parse(final String strHttpGet)
            throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Future<String> jsonTask = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                        String decodeJson = decodeJson(strHttpGet);
                        return decodeJson;
                    }

                    private String decodeJson(String strHttpGet) {
                        // TODO do actual parsing
                        return null;
                    }
                });
        // Allow the parsing to take one second
        return jsonTask.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```